# Xilinx ARM compiler doesn't complain about void pointer arithmetic, and it produces correct results. Why?

Tags: c, pointers

I have used the following code to read from an address space in Xilinx ARM Linux using their compiler for the past year, and it has worked (as in, compiled with no errors and produced the expected results):

```
void *ctl_ptr = mmap(NULL,Length , PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, ctl_addr);


// Read Status
int status = *((unsigned *)(ctl_ptr + C_FIFO_ISR));

// Clear Interrupts
*((unsigned *)(ctl_ptr + C_FIFO_ISR)) = 0xffffff;
```

A coworker mentioned today that this code shouldn't even work because it's void pointer arithmetic. Now I'm baffled as to exactly why it's been working all this time?

Is this an example of void pointer arithmatic (which it looks like it is), and if so, why does it work?

---

MORE INFO:

I've been using Xilinx SDK 2014.1 and this is the compile result for a file containing the above:

```
19:09:55 **** Auto Build of configuration Debug for project ZynqPSPLTest ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/ZynqPSPLTest.c
Invoking: ARM Linux gcc compiler
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ZynqPSPLTest.d" -MT"src/ZynqPSPLTest.d" -o "src/ZynqPSPLTest.o" "../src/ZynqPSPLTest.c"
Finished building: ../src/ZynqPSPLTest.c

Building target: ZynqPSPLTest.elf
Invoking: ARM Linux gcc linker
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -o "ZynqPSPLTest.elf"  ./src/ZynqPSPLTest.o   
Finished building target: ZynqPSPLTest.elf

make --no-print-directory post-build
Copy Elf to share
cp /media/work/stacey/zynq_eval/EvalDebug/sdk/ZynqPSPLTest/Debug/ZynqPSPLTest.elf /home/stacey/build_share

Invoking: ARM Linux Print Size
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-size ZynqPSPLTest.elf  |tee "ZynqPSPLTest.elf.size"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  11339     328       4   11671    2d97 ZynqPSPLTest.elf
Finished building: ZynqPSPLTest.elf.size


19:09:56 Build Finished (took 720ms)
```

And here's the version output:

```
[stacey@centos6 bin]$ ./arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/media/work/Xilinx/SDK/2014.1/gnu/arm/lin/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/src/gcc-4.8-2013.11/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-arch=armv5te --with-arch=armv7-a --with-cpu=cortex-a9 --with-float=softfp --with-fpu=neon-fp16 --disable-multilib --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} %{funwind-tables|fno-unwind-tables|mabi=*|ffreestanding|nostdlib:;:-funwind-tables} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2013 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=11 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=53' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-lto --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-pkgversion='Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-53' --with-bugurl=https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/install/opt/codesourcery/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/libc --with-gmp=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/obj/pkg-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/xilinx-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/obj/pkg-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/xilinx-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-mpc=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/obj/pkg-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/xilinx-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-isl=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/obj/pkg-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/xilinx-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --with-cloog=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/obj/pkg-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/xilinx-2013.11-53-arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi.extras/host-libs-i686-pc-linux-gnu/usr --disable-libgomp --disable-libitm --disable-libssp --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/install/opt/codesourcery/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/janisjo/build7/2013.11-xilinx-linux-respin1/install/opt/codesourcery/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/bin SED=sed
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` has an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) that allows void pointer arithmetic, see [the documentation: Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html):

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on
>   pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by
>   treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that sizeof is also allowed on void and on
>   function types, and returns 1.
>
> The option -Wpointer-arith requests a warning if these extensions are
>   used.

Answer (score 1):

The original C compiler (Unix v 6, c. 1975) worked that way too.  It is ignoring the `void` and treating the pointer as though it is just a number.  Or—another way to look at it—is that it regards a `void *` as the same as a `char *`.

The original c compiler also did higher level pointer object stuff correctly.  It would *have to* so that indexing `struct {int a, b;} mystruct [20]` worked as expected.

Comment: [I don't see any `void` keyword.](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6/usr/source/c/c00.c#L25-L54)